# How does execution flow through a promise and its .then() block?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am working through a Udemy course on JavaScript. In one project, the instructor ends up creating this code to demonstrate both the fetch API and promises:

```
function fetchUser() {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data.results[0]);
            displayUser(data.results[0]);
            hideSpinner();
        });
}
```

displayUser() is just a function to update the DOM with the data received from the random user API.

What I'm confused about is what using promises gets us here. If we used an XHR object to make the request and waited until the response came in to continue execution, this would be no less asynchronous, correct?

Can anybody recommend a source that demonstrates a useful (though still simple) implementation of promises for asynchronous tasks? When I search online, I just get explanations of the syntax rather than an explanation for how and when they're useful.

Comment: `and waited` ... how do you do that with XHR? You use the `load` event, or `.onload` callback ... Promises' `.then` is just a callback too - note: most people use async/await these days with Promises, which makes the code even cleaner to read (but it's still asynchronous of course)

Comment: *"If we used an XHR object to make the request and waited until the response came in"* - that *is* what is happening here. That's what the promise allows you to do.

Comment: @user229044 I think OP means literally `XMLHttpRequest` with its event callbacks which aren't promise-based

Comment: It's [events all the way down](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop). Event listeners like `onload` / `onreadystatechange` are fired by events occurring. Promise resolution happens in exactly the same way